# How to merge feature branches into master so that new changes also reflected

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I made a feature branch (let's call it branch A) on top of someone else feature branch(let's call it branch B). Now there were some changes made to branch B and then it was pushed to master. Those changes were not reflected in branch A in which I was working but now I need to merge branch A in master. So if I merge it will Github keep the changes of Branch B or after merging the master branch will be like Branch A ( i.e. my branch which does not contains Branch B new changes)
There are no merge conflicts since I was working on different files.

Comment: If my answer good for you I will be glad that you check the mark on my answer

Comment: Already added @Ben.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation the `master` branch will contain both

branches `A` & `B`. And if you have been working on different files

then there will be no conflicts between the branches.

Comment: so the master will retain the new changes of B when I will merge A with master despite A containing the old unchanged B branch code. Is that correct?

Comment: yes (if you in branch `A`  didn't touched that old code of branch `B` it will be merged automatically )

Answer (score 1):

The best way to keep the tree clean would be to merge B into A and then merge A into master.

But only if the **changes in the branch B change the feature in branch A**, otherwise merge directly into master ( Look at the answer from [@ben-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11522395/ben-s)).